# Bash count occurences based on parameters

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, counting

I'm new to bash shell and I have to do a script with a csv file.

The file is a list of the participants, countries, sports and medals achieved.

when executing the script, I should give as parameters the `nationality` (column 3) and the `sport` (column 8). The script should return the amount of participants of that country for that sport, and the amount of medals achieved.

The amount of medals achieved is the sum of the columns "gold" "silver" "bronze" of each row which are columns 9,10 and 11.

I cannot use grep, awk, sed or csvkit.

So far, I have this code but I'm stuck with the medal counting part.

```
nacionality=$1
sport=$2
columns= cut -d, -f 3,8 athletes.csv
echo columns | tr -cd $nacionality,$sport | wc -c
```

Could anyone help me?

The file is: https://github.com/flother/rio2016/blob/master/athletes.csv

The name of the file is `script2_4.sh`

An example of the output is:

```
./script2_4.sh POL rowing

 Participants, Medals


 26, 6
```

A sample of the file:

```
id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
736041664,A Jesus Garcia,ESP,male,1969-10-17,1.72,64,athletics,0,0,0,
532037425,A Lam Shin,KOR,female,1986-09-23,1.68,56,fencing,0,0,0,
435962603,Aaron Brown,CAN,male,1992-05-27,1.98,79,athletics,0,0,1,
521041435,Aaron Cook,MDA,male,1991-01-02,1.83,80,taekwondo,0,0,0,
33922579,Aaron Gate,NZL,male,1990-11-26,1.81,71,cycling,0,0,0,
173071782,Aaron Royle,AUS,male,1990-01-26,1.80,67,triathlon,0,0,0,
266237702,Aaron Russell,USA,male,1993-06-04,2.05,98,volleyball,0,0,1,
382571888,Aaron Younger,AUS,male,1991-09-25,1.93,100,aquatics,0,0,0,
87689776,Aauri Lorena Bokesa,ESP,female,1988-12-14,1.80,62,athletics,0,0,0,
997877719,Ababel Yeshaneh,ETH,female,1991-07-22,1.65,54,athletics,0,0,0,
343694681,Abadi Hadis,ETH,male,1997-11-06,1.70,63,athletics,0,0,0,
591319906,Abbas Abubakar Abbas,BRN,male,1996-05-17,1.75,66,athletics,0,0,0,
258556239,Abbas Qali,IOA,male,1992-10-11,,,aquatics,0,0,0,
376068084,Abbey D'Agostino,USA,female,1992-05-25,1.61,49,athletics,0,0,0,
162792594,Abbey Weitzeil,USA,female,1996-12-03,1.78,68,aquatics,1,1,0,
521036704,Abbie Brown,GBR,female,1996-04-10,1.76,71,rugby sevens,0,0,0,
149397772,Abbos Rakhmonov,UZB,male,1998-07-07,1.61,57,wrestling,0,0,0,
256673338,Abbubaker Mobara,RSA,male,1994-02-18,1.75,64,football,0,0,0,
337369662,Abby Erceg,NZL,female,1989-11-20,1.75,68,football,0,0,0,
334169879,Abd Elhalim Mohamed Abou,EGY,male,1989-06-03,2.10,88,volleyball,0,0,0,
215053268,Abdalaati Iguider,MAR,male,1987-03-25,1.73,57,athletics,0,0,0,
763711985,Abdalelah Haroun,QAT,male,1997-01-01,1.85,80,athletics,0,0,0,
```

Comment: If you exclude basic unix commands then you have to tell us which commands you can use.  "Only very basic commands." means nothing.  Including a sample of the file inline instead of an external link to a 824k file which may die at any time.

Comment: Let's just say I cannot use grep, sed, awk or any csvkit command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure bash implementation.  Build a hash from field name to position (`$h`):

```
#!/bin/bash

file=athletes.csv
nationality=$1
sport=$2

IFS=, read -a l < "$file"
declare -A h
for pos in "h${!l[@]}"
do
    h["${l[$pos]}"]=$pos
done

declare -i participants=0
declare -i medals=0
while IFS=, read -a l
do
    if [ "${l[${h["nationality"]}]}" = "$nationality" ] &&
        [ "${l[${h["sport"]}]}" = "$sport" ]
    then
    ((participants++))
        medals=$((
        $medals +
        "${l[${h["gold"]}]}" +
        "${l[${h["silver"]}]}" +
        "${l[${h["bronze"]}]}"
    ))
    fi
done < "$file"
echo "Participants, Medals"
echo "$participants, $medals"
```

and example output with the first 4 lines of input:

```
$ ./script2_4.sh CAN athletics
Participants, Medals
1, 1
```

Comment: Thanks Allan but how could I unify the 3 values in one variable? in the CAN athletics case, it should show 1 (because 0+0+1)

Comment: Initial question was not clear.  Updated answer.

Comment: I tried but it does not work. It runs every line saying "order not found". I have the same exact code

Comment: I updated the code slightly.  Figure out where the error is coming from by inserting exit at various points.  It works for me as is.

Comment: Hi Allan. Thanks, we are almost there. It works for the participants but the medals total is not being shown, I tried different combinations

Comment: For example, USA aquatics should return 85, 89 but it's returning 85, 1

Comment: Fixed with ```medals=$(($medals + ...)```