# Most repeated string based on two arguments strings csv file. BASH

Tags: bash, shell, csv

First exercise with bash, this is taking a lot of time...

I'm trying to create a script where, giving 2 arguments (height,weight) on [athletes.csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flother/rio2016/master/athletes.csv) returns number of coincidence on both values and predominant nationality based on that. And if that was not enough, if predominance is equal for 2 countries, then `echo` predominance with lowest id.

Also i can't use awk, grep, sed or csvkit.

Here is csv header:

```
id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
736041664,A Jesus Garcia,ESP,male,1969-10-17,1.72,64,athletics,0,0,0,
532037425,A Lam Shin,KOR,female,1986-09-23,1.68,56,fencing,0,0,0,
435962603,Aaron Brown,CAN,male,1992-05-27,1.98,79,athletics,0,0,1,
521041435,Aaron Cook,MDA,male,1991-01-02,1.83,80,taekwondo,0,0,0,
33922579,Aaron Gate,NZL,male,1990-11-26,1.81,71,cycling,0,0,0,
173071782,Aaron Royle,AUS,male,1990-01-26,1.80,67,triathlon,0,0,0,
266237702,Aaron Russell,USA,male,1993-06-04,2.05,98,volleyball,0,0,1,
```

Until now:

```
count=0

while IFS=, read -a id _ nation _ _ height weight _ _ _ _; do

    if (( $height == "$2" )) && (( "$weight" == $3 )) ; then

        ((count++))
    fi

done < athletes.csv

echo "$count"
```

I have seen [a similiar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71717519/bash-count-occurences-based-on-parameters). But can't find the way to return the most common nationality (strings).

Looking for something similar to:

```
Count, Predominant_nationality 1.85 130
8460, BRA
```

Should i try to work the hole exercise with arrays instead trying with lopps? Probably i could do it indexes, but looks like arrays are 1d here?

Any help would be a blessing

Comment: Why are you doing analytics with `bash`!? This is error prone, and should never be done, specially when there are so many real options. I would use Python with `pandas`, one could also use `R`.

Comment: Completely agree. I know some py and R. It could be solved in 5min but i have no chocie. I have tried in many ways and limitations (awk,grep,csvkit) are killing me.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem of sorting and counting that can be resolved with Linux standard text utilities

```
csv='athletes.csv'
crit='1\.85,90'

echo "Count Predominant_nationality $crit"
# Get fields from csv and sort on filtered fields 2,3
cut -d ',' -f 1,3,6,7 "$csv" | grep "$crit" | sort -t ',' -k2,3 | tr ',' ' ' | \
# Count unique skipping first field, get first
uniq -f 1 -c | sort -n -k1,1nr -k2n | head -n1 | tr -s ' ' | \
# print result
cut -d ' ' -f 2,4 --output-delimiter='    '
```

Result

```
Count Predominant_nationality 1.85,90
2    BRA
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with current code:

- `read -a` says to read values into an array but what you really want is to read the values into individual variables
- `read -r` is typical in this type of scenario (`-r` disables backslashes as escapes)
- the `if (( ... ))` constucts are typically used for integer comparisons and since heights are non-integer (eg, `1.85`) it's probably best to stick with string comparisons (especially since we're only interested in equality matches)

Setup; instead of downloading the link/data file I'll add 4x bogus lines to OP's sample input, making sure all 4x lines match OP's sample search parameters (`1.85` and `130`):

```
$ cat athletes.csv
id,name,nationality,sex,date_of_birth,height,weight,sport,gold,silver,bronze,info
736041664,A Jesus Garcia,ESP,male,1969-10-17,1.72,64,athletics,0,0,0,
532037425,A Lam Shin,KOR,female,1986-09-23,1.68,56,fencing,0,0,0,
435962603,Aaron Brown,CAN,male,1992-05-27,1.98,79,athletics,0,0,1,
521041435,Aaron Cook,MDA,male,1991-01-02,1.83,80,taekwondo,0,0,0,
33922579,Aaron Gate,NZL,male,1990-11-26,1.81,71,cycling,0,0,0,
173071782,Aaron Royle,AUS,male,1990-01-26,1.80,67,triathlon,0,0,0,
266237702,Aaron Russell,USA,male,1993-06-04,2.05,98,volleyball,0,0,1,
134,Aaron XX1,USA,male,1993-06-04,1.85,130,volleyball,0,0,1,
127,Aaron XX2,CAD,male,1993-06-04,1.85,130,volleyball,0,0,1,
34,Aaron XX3,USA,male,1993-06-04,1.85,130,volleyball,0,0,1,
27,Aaron XX4,CAD,male,1993-06-04,1.85,130,volleyball,0,0,1,
```

One `bash` idea:

```
arg1="1.85"
arg2="130"

maxid=99999999999

unset counts ids maxcount
declare -A counts ids
maxcount=0

while IFS=, read -r id _ nation _ _ height weight _
do
    if [[ "${height}" == "${arg1}" && "${weight}" == "${arg2}" ]]
    then
        (( counts[${nation}]++ ))

        # keep track of overall max count

        [[ "${counts[${nation}]}" -gt "${maxcount}"  ]] && maxcount="${counts[${nation}]}"

        # keep track of min(id) for each nation

        [[ "${id}" -lt "${ids[${nation}]:-${maxid}}" ]] && ids[${nation}]="${id}"
    fi
done < athletes.csv
```

Alternatively, since it looks like our search patterns are together and can only occur in one location within a line, we can use `grep` to filter out only the matching rows:

```
$ grep ",${arg1},${arg2}," athletes.csv
134,Aaron XX1,USA,male,1993-06-04,1.85,130,volleyball,0,0,1,
127,Aaron XX2,CAD,male,1993-06-04,1.85,130,volleyball,0,0,1,
34,Aaron XX3,USA,male,1993-06-04,1.85,130,volleyball,0,0,1,
27,Aaron XX4,CAD,male,1993-06-04,1.85,130,volleyball,0,0,1,
```

We can then feed this result to the `while/read` loop and eliminte the need to test the `height/weight` variables, eg:

```
while IFS=, read -r id _ nation _
do
   (( counts[${nation}]++ ))
   [[ "${counts[${nation}]}" -gt "${maxcount}"  ]] && maxcount="${counts[${nation}]}"
   [[ "${id}" -lt "${ids[${nation}]:-${maxid}}" ]] && ids[${nation}]="${id}"
done < <(grep ",${arg1},${arg2}," athletes.csv)
```

At this point both of these `while/read` loops produce:

```
$ typeset -p counts ids maxcount
declare -A counts=([USA]="2" [CAD]="2" )
declare -A ids=([USA]="34" [CAD]="27" )
declare -- maxcount="2"
```

From here OP can loop through the list of nations (`"${!counts[@]}"`) looking for counts that are equal to `maxcount` and when found then apply an additional check to see if the nation has the lowest id (`ids[]`) seen so far in the loop.  At the end of the loop OP should have the country a) count that is equal to `maxcount` and b) with the lowest id.